# CSS: clear: left working too well?

Tags: css, css-float, firefox3.6

I have an issue every now and again and I'm not sure what the solution is.

I have a 2 column layout (left strit, and then main area).  In the main area, I sometimes have a secondary 2 column layout (eg - for a news section, where there is an icon, and then the news item).  When I clear left on the new item, instead of clearing the image above it (which is left floated) it clears the nav bar on the left.

Here is a [**sample**](http://www.yishrei.org/news/).  This seems to be an issue on FF3.6, whereas IE8 seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the `#mainContent` add `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;` to clear the floats. Read more here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

On your `<div>` that contains each news section, try adding `overflow: hidden`. I think that should isolate the uses of `clear` within that `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using columns for you news columns to separate icons and text - what if you use a "float:left" on the image?  For example, look on this page:

http://clayclerk.com/

The Css styling for the image is:

```
.imageleft {
float:      left;
margin-right:   10px;
}
```